# Make sure a date is even 5 minutes

Tags: javascript

I want to make sure a date is even 5 minutes. 
Im using this simple check...

```
var date = new Date();
if (date.getTime() % 300000 === 0) {
    console.log('date is even 5 minutes');
}
```

Can someone see any flaws in this method? 
Is there a point in time when this will not work?

**EDIT** This is for validating POST input from a user...

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code

Comment: flaw here is that you only accept 1 ms every 5 minutes. That's very precise. You may want to check only to the second, or to the minute (`date.getTime() % 300000 < 1000` or `date.getTime() % 300000 < (60 * 1000)`)

Comment: I wonder how [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) are treated.  Looks like new Date() is ignoring them.  Hmm....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want to know exactly the millisecond when the date is `even 5 minutes` than this is correct. But if you have a code that you want to execute every 5 minutes that this is not correct because you will miss this moment a lot of times, if not every time.

Comment: @Pablo Where do you suggest I ask this instead?

Comment: Here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
var date = new Date();
if ( parseInt(date.getTime() / 1000 ) % 300 === 0) {
    console.log('date is even 5 minutes');
}
```

**EDIT**

Added the possibility to define the precision of the check:

```
var 
  date = new Date(),
  precision = 1000; // precision in ms

if ( parseInt( date.getTime() / precision, 10 ) % ( 300000 / precision ) === 0) {
    console.log('date is even 5 minutes');
}
```

**EDIT 2**
based on question change try:
find the closest 5 minutes multiple date

```
Math.floor(( new Date().getTime() + 2.5*6000 ) / 30000 ) * 30000 )
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does and why it's better?

Comment: You get the date, then get the seconds by taking the integer part of the division by 1000 and next check if is multiple of 300 (5 minutes in seconds)

Comment: for perfect solution, it is better to use radix for parseInt.

Comment: @Juhana it depends on what you are trying to do this code is not as precise as your code...

Comment: @brso05 - I think it's almost impossible that his code prints on the console, 1ms is too small

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik Don't assume though make sure he understands the difference because that may actually be what he wants...

Comment: I edited my questions. This is not to be used as a trigger... but rather to validate input from a POST.

Comment: @AndersÖstman - So you can only send a POST only when the time is exactly multiples of 5 minutes? why?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik - No =). The user is asked to provide a Date. This date should be even 5 minutes.

Comment: @AndersÖstman - try with: Math.floor(( new Date().getTime() + 2.5*6000 ) / 30000 ) * 30000 )